# When Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() returns null, what is going on?

Tags: java, classloader

Start with a JAR file that contains a JAX-WS SPI text file in /META-INF, and then the class to which it points. Put it into the classpath. Set the contextClassLoader for the current thread to null.

Call the `Service` class from the JAX-WS API in JDK 1.6, and start stepping through it. In the absence of a context class loader, this code will call static methods of `Class` to find things.

It will successfully find the SPI file. But it won't find the .class that it names.

If you really want to try this for yourself, grab Apache CXF 2.2.10, put it on classpath, and null out the context class loader.

This wasn't an exercise in pointless masochism: it turns out that when Open Office invokes a Java Extension ('UNO'), it leaves the context class loader `null`. It took some significant <del>proctology</del> archeology to figure this out. Which left me wondering, is there a JDK bug that explains the inconsistent results, or some specified behavior that I don't understand?

Comment: Looks like it is using the system class loader (includes classpath classes) to load the services file but the bootstrap class loader to the load the class. `grep -R Class.forName . | grep FactoryFinder` is roughly evenly split on which to choose (don't you just <3 clone-and-own code?). Of course, if the same code was loaded from anything other than the system, extension or boot loader, then it wouldn't even be able to find itself.

Comment: @Tom, well, it's comforting to be able to blame this on someone else. Care to make this into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @irr the question is, why the inconsistent class loading results. The answer is: because the reference JAX-WS impl included in the JRE makes inconsistent class loading calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been various bugs raised for this sort of thing; e.g. scan the results of [this query](http://search.oracle.com/search/search?group=Sun+Defects&site=bugs.sun.com&q=getContextClassLoader).  The general Sun response is that these are features not bugs, and will not be fixed; e.g. https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4155645.

The bottom line is that `getContextClassLoader` *can* return `null`.

Comment: Sure. But it's their JAX-WS code that is malfunctioning when it is null.

Comment: Shrug.  Stuff happens.  Raise a bug report against JAX-WS.